# Collapsible Radial Tidy Tree found in ObservableHQ is not collapsing after mouse click if I use d3 v6 instead of d3 v5

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization

I have been trying to reproduce this [ObservableHQ code on collapsible tree](https://observablehq.com/@esperanc/d3-radial-tidy-tree) into regular html-css-js format. Below is my implementation.

```js
height = 1000;//+svg.attr("height");
    width = 1000;//+svg.attr("width");
    radius = width/2;

    tree = d3.tree()
    .size([2 * Math.PI, radius])
    .separation((a, b) => (a.parent == b.parent ? 1 : 2) / a.depth)
    const data = d3.json("https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/d3/d3-hierarchy@master/test/data/flare.json");
    //const data = d3.json("network.json");
    data.then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
  
      var svg = d3.select("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height",height)
                
      var g = svg.append("g")
                // .attr("transform",'translate('+width/2+','+height/2+')')
      
     const linkgroup = g.append("g")
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "#555")
      .attr("stroke-opacity", 0.4)
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5);

  const nodegroup = g.append("g")
      .attr("stroke-linejoin", "round")
      .attr("stroke-width", 3);

  function newdata (animate = true) {
    let root = tree(d3.hierarchy(data));
    let links_data = root.links();
    let links = linkgroup
      .selectAll("path")
      .data(links_data, d => d.source.data.name+"_"+d.target.data.name);
    
    links.exit().remove();
    
    let newlinks = links
      .enter()
      .append("path")
      .attr("d", d3.linkRadial()
        .angle(d => d.x)
        .radius(0.1));

    
    let t = d3.transition()
      .duration(animate ? 400 : 0)
      .ease(d3.easeLinear)
      .on("end", function() {
          const box = g.node().getBBox();
          svg.transition().duration(1000).attr("viewBox", `${box.x} ${box.y} ${box.width} ${box.height}`);
      });
    
    let alllinks = linkgroup.selectAll("path")
    alllinks
        .transition(t)
        .attr("d", d3.linkRadial()
            .angle(d => d.x)
            .radius(d => d.y));

    let nodes_data = root.descendants().reverse();
    let nodes = nodegroup
      .selectAll("g")
      .data(nodes_data, function (d) { 
        if (d.parent) {
          return d.parent.data.name+d.data.name;
        }
        return d.data.name});
    
    nodes.exit().remove();

    let newnodes = nodes
      .enter().append("g");
    
    let allnodes = animate ? nodegroup.selectAll("g").transition(t) : nodegroup.selectAll("g");
    allnodes
      .attr("transform", d => `
        rotate(${d.x * 180 / Math.PI - 90})
        translate(${d.y},0)
      `);
    
    newnodes.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .on ("click", function (d) {
      let altChildren = d.data.altChildren || [];
      let children = d.data.children;
      d.data.children = altChildren;
      d.data.altChildren = children;
      newdata (); 
    });
        
    nodegroup.selectAll("g circle").attr("fill", function (d) {
      let altChildren = d.data.altChildren || [];
      let children = d.data.children;
      return d.children || (children && (children.length > 0 || altChildren.length > 0)) ? "#555" : "#999" } );

    newnodes.append("text")
        .attr("dy", "0.31em")
        .text(d => d.data.name)
      .clone(true).lower()
        .attr("stroke", "white");
    
    nodegroup.selectAll("g text")
      .attr("x", d => d.x < Math.PI === !d.children ? 6 : -6)
      .attr("text-anchor", d => d.x < Math.PI === !d.children ? "start" : "end")
      .attr("transform", d => d.x >= Math.PI ? "rotate(180)" : null);

  }

 newdata (false);
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
      <svg>
      </svg>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It is running perfectly fine here as a snippet inside Stackoverflow, but when I am running it in my localhost web server this is showing me an error when I click any of the nodes:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'altChildren' of undefined
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> ((index):101)
    at SVGCircleElement.<anonymous> (d3.v6.min.js:2)
```

Line 101 (where the error happens when I click on a node) is the following:

```
let altChildren = d.data.altChildren || [];
```

I am trying to understand what should be changed in my code so that when I click any node it gets collapsed/expanded.

Edit:

I just realized this is an artifact of using d3 v6 locally. In the code snippet that is working here is using d3 v5. So Now I realized this is happening because of d3 v6.

Now my updated question is that, what does it require to make sure it is running with d3 v6?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [d3 v6 migration guide](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3v6-migration-guide), local events are passed as the first argument to all event listeners. In this case we have a mouse click event listener.

So changing `.on ("click", function (d) {` to `.on ("click", function (event,d) {` as below:

from

```
newnodes.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .on ("click", function (d) {
      let altChildren = d.data.altChildren || [];
      let children = d.data.children;
      d.data.children = altChildren;
      d.data.altChildren = children;
      newdata (); 
    });
```

to

```
newnodes.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 4.5)
        .on ("click", function (event,d) {
      let altChildren = d.data.altChildren || [];
      let children = d.data.children;
      d.data.children = altChildren;
      d.data.altChildren = children;
      newdata (); 
    });
```

did the trick.